# Get DATA from xml google maps

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I get data from Google Maps in XML format. All functions are working, but I have little problem. It only shows me the last data. Why is that, and how can I solve it?

This is my code ([jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PHcvk/))

```
function getline() {


downloadUrl("line.php", function(doc) {



        var g = google.maps;

        var xmlDoc = xmlParse(doc);

        bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();

      // ========= Now process the polylines ===========
      var lines = xmlDoc.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("line");

      // read each line
      for (var a = 0; a < lines.length; a++) {
        // get any line attributes
        var colour = lines[a].getAttribute("colour");
        var width  = parseFloat(lines[a].getAttribute("width"));
        var diameter = lines[a].getAttribute("diameter");
        var project = lines[a].getAttribute("projectid");
        var contract = lines[a].getAttribute("contract");
        var comp = lines[a].getAttribute("complated");
        var id = lines[a].getAttribute("id_line");
        // read each point on that line
        var points = lines[a].getElementsByTagName("point");
        var pts = [];
        var length = 0;
        var point = null;

        for (var i = 0; i < points.length; i++) {
           pts[i] = new g.LatLng(parseFloat(points[i].getAttribute("lng")),
                                parseFloat(points[i].getAttribute("lat")));
           if (i > 0) {
             length += pts[i-1].distanceFrom(pts[i]);
             if (isNaN(length)) { alert("["+i+"] length="+length+" segment="+pts[i-1].distanceFrom(pts[i])) };
           }
           bounds.extend(pts[i]);
           point = pts[parseInt(i/2)];

                var info = "<b> Contract: </b>" + contract + " <br/> <b>Project: </b>" + project +"<br/>  <b>Diameter: </b>" + diameter + " <br/> <b>Complated: </b>" + comp + "  <hr><br/><a class=\"inline-link-1\" href=\"#\">Change Data</a> <a class=\"inline-link-1\" href=\"#\">Edit</a> >" + id +"" ;

        }
        // length *= 0.000621371192; // miles/meter 

 if (comp < 1) { 
 colorr = '#FA0505' }

 if (comp > 0 && comp < 25 ) { 
 colorr = '#FFA640' }

 if (comp > 24 && comp < 50) { 
 colorr = '#FFFD91' }

 if (comp > 49 && comp < 75) { 
 colorr = '#E8E400' }

 if (comp > 74 && comp < 100) { 
 colorr = '#BFFFAD' }

 if (comp == 100) { 
 colorr = '#0F8500' }


        var polyline = new g.Polyline({
                          map:map,
                          path:pts,
                          strokeColor:colorr,
                          strokeWeight:width,
                          clickable: true
                          });
       //createClickablePolyline(polyloine, html, label, point, length);
     //  map.addOverlay(polyline);


  google.maps.event.addListener(polyline,'mouseover', function() {


        this.setOptions({strokeColor: '#690469' });
           this.setOptions({strokeOpacity: 1.0 });
           this.setOptions({strokeWeight: 4 });
  });

     google.maps.event.addListener(polyline,'mouseout', function() {


        this.setOptions({strokeColor: colorr });
           this.setOptions({strokeOpacity: 1.0 });
           this.setOptions({strokeWeight: 4 });
  });


  var  mpenc = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
  google.maps.event.addListener(polyline,'click', function(event) {
    mpenc.setContent(info, this);
    mpenc.setPosition(event.latLng, this);
    mpenc.open(map);
  });

      }
      map.fitBounds(bounds);




    });



}
```

Comment: You mean all elements generated by the loop have the value of the points.length element? you are probably not closing over the loop variable correctly, have a look at this [so about it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example)

Comment: @brio Please! make sure you should always post code here,don't just drop the link only

Comment: thanks for answer.. Can your explain where is my error? i cant find it yet.. I can show your my xml if need.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Google Maps API V3 infoWindow - All infoWindows displaying same content](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4897316/google-maps-api-v3-infowindow-all-infowindows-displaying-same-content)

Comment: @Dr.Molle I know i read all it.. But cant understand.

Comment: You should leave your code (in addition to the link to jsfiddle...).  Can you provide a link to the XML for the data you are having trouble parsing (or a snippet of XML that exhibits the problem)?

Comment: yes of course. i think its not a problem with xml..  http://nn-gis.com/map/line.php

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you copied some code and changed it.  Why is this commented out?

```
//createClickablePolyline(polyline, html, label, point, length);
```

That function is what gets closure on the "data", polyline and infowindow, so they are associated with each other (at least in my versions of this code).

[working v3 version of my code](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_GenericMapBrowser.asp?filename=SteveFossett.xml)

Comment: yes. its your code. i edited it.. but now i cant correct it to show data..it show me only last data

Comment: Compare your version to the working version.  Add the createClickablePolyline function back in.

Comment: i have markers and polylines. Markers working perfect. I call line when i need it with function getline(). when i add this function (creatpoly...) line not working without this func lines working but show only last data