# Google Maps InfoWindow [showing error]

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

Please look at my code. Where is the problem? 
When i call this function coordinates now work normally( lines not working) and info windows also not working.

So when delete `function binfowindow` everything is working but infowindow show only last data..

Updated!  Not a result!

```
 function getline() {

       var mpenc = new google.maps.InfoWindow();   
downloadUrl("line.php", function(doc) {



        var g = google.maps;

        var xmlDoc = xmlParse(doc);

        bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
        var markers = xmlDoc.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("marker");
      // ========= Now process the polylines ===========
      var lines = xmlDoc.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("line");

      // read each line
      for (var a = 0; a < lines.length; a++) {
        // get any line attributes
       var colour = lines[a].getAttribute("colour");
        var width  = parseFloat(lines[a].getAttribute("width"));
        var diameter = lines[a].getAttribute("diameter");
        var project = lines[a].getAttribute("projectid");
        var contract = lines[a].getAttribute("contract");
        var comp = lines[a].getAttribute("complated");
        var id = lines[a].getAttribute("id_line");
        var html = "men ?" + id + " I: ";
        // read each point on that line
        var points = lines[a].getElementsByTagName("point");
        var pts = [];
        var length = 0;
        var point = null;
        for (var i = 0; i < points.length; i++) {
           pts[i] = new g.LatLng(parseFloat(points[i].getAttribute("lng")),
                                parseFloat(points[i].getAttribute("lat")));
           if (i > 0) {
             length += pts[i-1].distanceFrom(pts[i]);
             if (isNaN(length)) { alert("["+i+"] length="+length+" segment="+pts[i-1].distanceFrom(pts[i])) };
           }
           bounds.extend(pts[i]);
           point = pts[parseInt(i/2)];
        }
        // length *= 0.000621371192; // miles/meter 


  if (comp < 1) { 
 colorr = '#FA0505' }

 if (comp > 0 && comp < 25 ) { 
 colorr = '#FFA640' }

 if (comp > 24 && comp < 50) { 
 colorr = '#FFFD91' }

 if (comp > 49 && comp < 75) { 
 colorr = '#E8E400' }

 if (comp > 74 && comp < 100) { 
 colorr = '#BFFFAD' }

 if (comp == 100) { 
 colorr = '#0F8500' }


        var poly = new g.Polyline({
                          map:map,
                          path:pts,
                          strokeColor:colorr,
                          strokeWeight:width,
                          clickable: true
                          });



google.maps.event.addListener(poly,'mouseover', function() {


        this.setOptions({strokeColor: '#690469' });
           this.setOptions({strokeOpacity: 1.0 });
           this.setOptions({strokeWeight: 4 });



  });

     google.maps.event.addListener(poly,'mouseout', function() {


        this.setOptions({strokeColor: colorr });
           this.setOptions({strokeOpacity: 1.0 });
           this.setOptions({strokeWeight: 4 });
  });


    var funcs = [];

function createfunc(i) {
    return function() { 


  google.maps.event.addListener(poly,'click', function(event) {
    mpenc.setContent(html +i);
    mpenc.setPosition(event.latLng);
    mpenc.open(map);
  });



    };
}

for (var i = 0; i < lines.length; i++) {
    funcs[i] = createfunc(i);
}

for (var j = 0; j < lines.length; j++) {
    funcs[j]();                        // and now let's run each one to see
}  







      }
      map.fitBounds(bounds);

    });



}
```

Comment: You're not saying what specifically is wrong... Check your browser's error console for any errors, and read [JavaScript closure inside loops](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example) for a detailed explanation of a problem you need to be aware of in `bInfoWindow`. (And indent your code consistently.)

Comment: thanks for answer. I saw this post.. But i cant implement this ((.. 3 days i work on this but cant implement ((

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get DATA from xml google maps](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15697781/get-data-from-xml-google-maps)

Comment: Do not repost questions. That serves you no good.

Comment: not a dublicate. problem is showing data..not a last data!